# Angular 4 - fade in view on route change using angular animations

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-animations

**Question:**
Angular 4 - fade in view on route change using angular animations

**Problem:**

Currently, the view fades in onload of the website but not when the routes change.
I want the view to fade in always on route change as well.

**This is my HTML: (possibly the issue is here???)**

```
  <div class="page" [@fadeInTransition]>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

**This is my app component:**

```
import { Component, HostBinding  } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { MetadataService } from 'ng2-metadata/index';

import { fadeAnimation } from "./animations/fade.animation";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  animations: [fadeAnimation()] 
})

export class AppComponent {
    @HostBinding('@fadeInTransition') fadeInTransition;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private metadataService: MetadataService) {
    }
}
```

**This is my animation (which I import):**

```
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export function fadeInAnimation() {
    return trigger('fadeInTransition', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate('2s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ])
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not DRY but.. Add the following to every component works.

```
import { fadeAnimation } from "./animations/fade.animation";

@Component({
  selector: "app-some-other-component",      
  animations: [fadeAnimation()] 
})

@HostBinding('@fadeInTransition') fadeInTransition;
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. It works that way but like you said it's not the best solution. Let me know if you find an app component solution.

Comment: I've found this solution but it doesnt work on change of route either: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-animate-router-transitions-6de179e00204